# addCSS not working in PrestaShop, for ModuleAdminController

Tags: prestashop

I'm busy creating an Admin module and extending the ModuleAdminController class. I'm trying to add some CSS by using the following:

```
class AdminPrintspecJobsController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();
        $this->addCss(_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name . "/css/printspec_table.css");
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I refresh my admin page, in Chrome, the Network panel indicates the file is added to the DOM, but it fails with an HTTP 404, not found error.

My folder structure looks as follows:

```
.
├── AdminTab.gif
├── config.xml
├── controllers
│   └── admin
│       ├── AdminPrintspecJobs.php
│       └── AdminTab.php
├── css
│   └── printspec_table.css
├── printspec.php
└── views
    └── templates
        └── admin
            └── printspec_jobs
                └── jobs.tpl
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to .htaccess. If I empty the file, I can access my CSS directly, as with other modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working by turning Friendly URLs off and then on again.